# Scala Future.failed throws the exception passed to it

Tags: scala, exception, future, throws

I'm using the constructor Future.failed to create a failed future, but the failed future still throws the exception when I think it should not.

The method session.loadAll does throw an exception.

I'm also using the Play Framework

[image: Future.failed throws an exception image]

It even happens using a try-catch block
[image]

Comment: I have absolutely no idea what you asked. Method `loadAll` throws an exception, OK, your pattern matching catches it, OK, then you return another `Future.failed` wrapping a new `Exception`, OK. What's the problem? Also, what's with the screenshots?

Comment: @slouc My intention is to return a Future wrapping an exception as you said, the problem is that instead of returning the future, the exception is thrown. That's what I'm trying to show with the images. The application should not crash because no exception is thrown (or, at least, that's what I want by wrapping the exception in a future)

Comment: Oh, I see. But the `Future.failed(new Exception())` part is definitely not the one throwing the exception. Something else is. Perhaps the part consuming the result of `getThings` isn't expecting a failed future (although I'm not sure why would the compiler show the exception in line 44 in that case). My screenshots comment was saying that you should always post code snippets, not images.

Comment: @slouc You're right, the problem is with the consumer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that `Future.failed` is not throwing the exception. It looks like it is, because the stack trace is generated at the place where the exception is created.

So, if you use a method like `Await.result`, or another method that assumes that a future is successful, you will see the exception re-thrown, but the stack trace will make it *look* as if it was thrown in `Future.failed`.

Comment: `Await.result` is generally discouraged as it is a blocking call.  If blocking is not required, `Future.onComplete` or `Future.onFailure` will follow the asynchronous pattern and be as performant or better.  

http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/futures.html further explains why this is a bad idea

Answer (score 1):

First, I'm not quite sure why you're using a future here because these don't look like asynchronous calls.

To answer your question, however, I'm not entirely sure what is going on here, but it looks like you need to be handling the exception.  The consumer of the future should use either `Future.onComplete` and pattern match a Failure type, or `Future.onFailure` and pattern match on Throwable types.

Scala docs on Future: http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/futures.html

Comment: You are right the problem is with the consumer, it was not handling the exception